# How to replace some characters from stringstream in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stringstream

I have a requirement to replace all the carriage returns/ Line feeds from a stringstream in a VC++ Project. I am very new to this and I tried the following:

```
strCustData.Replace("\r\n","")
```

But this is not working because `strCustData` is of type stringstream, not string. Please help me out in achieving this.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use a stream buffer to filter out the characters:

```c++
class filter : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    filter(std::ostream& os) : m_sbuf(os.rdbuf()) { }

    int_type overflow(int_type c) override
    {
        return m_sbuf->sputc(c == '\r' ? traits_type::eof() : c);
    }

    int sync() override { return m_sbuf->pubsync() ? 0 : -1; }
private:
    std::streambuf* m_sbuf;
};
```

Now you can use it like this:

```c++
filter f(strCustData);
std::ostream os(&f);

os <<"\r\n"; // '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

An ugly (memory duplicating because of using a `std::string` as buffer) way to do it is something like this:

```
// replace "foo" with "bar"
std::stringstream myStringStream("foobarfoobar");
std::string myString(myStringStream.str());

size_t start = 0;
while ((start = myString.find("foo", start)) != std::string::npos) {
    myString.replace(start, strlen("foo"), "bar");
}
myStringStream.str(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `stringstream` into a `std::string` - not CString like you seemingly tried to. [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has lots of functions that can be used to manipulate the characters.

Something like this (untested):

```
std::istringstream stream;
std::string str(stream.str());
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r', ' '); 
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n', ' ');
```

You could probably collapse the two replaces into one, but I am writing off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need the output in `stringstream` rather than `std::string`. Is there any way to convert back to `stringstream` after the replacement?

Comment: If you want to stay in streams you could pass the the data from one stream to another and manipulate each character as they pass through via (`get` or `read`).  Unless you are writing to disk then you will have to leave the confines of `stringstream` at some point.